# Is there any way to download old versions of appcompat libraries?

Tags: java, android, ant, dependencies, android-appcompat

While being in a transition period to Gradle, I still have to support both build systems - Gradle and Ant (for a while). Since the app is huge and with lots of dependencies, there are branches with different API/SDK targets and different appcompat versions, which all need to be built using both Gradle and Ant.

So: **no. I can't write a 1-line solution in build.gradle** and please don't suggest that.

I need a few appcompat-v4 and appcompat-v7 versions:

1. 22.1
2. 22.2
3. 23.1

Is there any way to get those? The SDK Manager does not allow downgrading or even having 2 different versions of the same library.. Maybe through jCenter/Bintray or MavenCentral, pre-built JARs...? I already have all the **resources** from AARs, so I'm missing the JARs only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this folder which contains all the AARs, by version: `.../android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/`

I managed to open the AAR inside the version I need using the Archive Manager (should open like a `.zip`), and browse the content. What I was looking for is `classes.jar`, that's where all the Java code is. This finally resolved the issue for me.